# How does a TLB manage memory translation for addresses that cross page boundaries?

Tags: cpu-architecture, hardware, virtual-memory, tlb, page-size

Let's say we have a page size of 4096 Bytes, and we have two contiguous virtual memory pages mapped to discontinuous physical pages, i.e

[x , x + 4096 * 2] - Maps to -> [A, A + 4096], [B, B + 4096]

```
x    x+4096  x+8192         A     A+4096   B     B+4096
|      |      |              |     |       |      |
|      |      |   --->       |     | ..... |      |
|      |      |              |     |       |      |
```

Let's say now we get an 8-byte memory access to address [x + 4090, x + 4098], which crosses page boundaries

```
x       x+4096   x+8192     
|  x+4090 |  x+4098 |
|     <---|--->     | 
|         |         |
```

1. How is address translation handled in the TLB in such a scenario?
2. Is it handled in the TLB, or is the page boundary cross-detected prior to memory access in the CPU pipeline (maybe in the Load/Store Unit)?
3. How is such a situation handled in architectures which support multiple page sizes, 4K, 2M, 1G etc.

Comment: If `x` is page aligned, then x+4090 to x+4098 not only crosses a page boundary, but also is a misaligned access, and also is a 9 byte range.  (FWIW, the answer to how this is implemented is going to be somewhat processor specific.)

Comment: It's handled as two separate accesses, each with their own TLB access.  Intel since Skylake makes page-split penalty a lot less bad than before, but a 4K split is still much worse throughput than splitting across a cache-line boundary within a page. (See [How can I accurately benchmark unaligned access speed on x86\_64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45128763)). The penalty on Skylake is the same for a split between two separate 4K pages vs. a 4K boundary within a 2M largepage; I wouldn't be surprised if that's the case on most CPUs.  I haven't tested 4K or 2M boundaries withing 1G hugepages.

Comment: [Address translation with multiple pagesize-specific TLBs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49842530) - there are techniques for building a TLB that allows different entries in the same TLB to have different page sizes.  IDK if it would be difficult for the CPU to detect that a 4K split is within a 2M largepage.  Or if it would be useful to detect that: the load execution unit still has to do the other half of the load separately since it's still a cache-line split.  But maybe it could avoid the slowest path if they put more effort (and transistors) into detecting largepages.